# Updating ArcGIS feature class from Python script not cooperating to code

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to update the Project_Name field in my feature class table with the following code:

```
    import arcpy 
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    with open(r'thepath.csv') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        mydict = {rows[1]:rows[15] for rows in reader}
    fc = 'gdb./Projects.fc'
    cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(["unique ID", "Project_Name"])
    for row in cursor:
      if row[0] in mydict:
           row[1] = mydict[row[0]]
           cursor.updateRow(row)
```

When I run this, it doesn't populate the feature class field from the CSV spreadsheet. Project_Name corresponds to the second column of the .csv spreadsheet and unique ID field is the very last column of the spreadsheet (column 16). I've haven't done this before but the guy I used to work with ran this and it worked. I have no idea what's up.

Comment: You are using arcpy.da.SearchCursor (which is read only) instead of arcpy.da.UpdateCursor.

Comment: and this syntax is incorrect...cursor = (["unique ID, "Project_Name"])

Comment: You're missing the updated `in_table` name (first parameter) and the field name should not have a space in it. Your indent scheme is also invalid.